# Get data from other website

Tags: .net, web-scraping

I want to retrieve data from other website.

The data is available after the search form is submitted. However, it is filtered by some criteria on each submission.

```
The website have 3 drop down fields
Type: Basketball, Baseball, Football and more...
Location: Loc1, Loc2, Loc3 and more...
Court: Court1, Court2, Court3 and more...
```

Each search result will retrieve information about 1 Type, 1 Location, 1 Court on each request. like this

```
Type: Basketball, Location: Loc 1, Court: Court 1
 8:00 -  9:00: Booked
 9:00 - 10:00: 
10:00 - 11:00: Booked
...
```

The website didn't provide any webservice or api. so that I wrote a .net program to loop all the above options to get all information for all types, locations and courts. But the website return an error "web is busy" when the program submitted more than 100+ times. I think it is the max requests limit.

Any suggestion of how can I retrieve all the information from that website?

Comment: throttle your requests.

Comment: What you are doing is basically a denial of service attack. The webserver takes countermeasures against this attack. If you do this often enough expect that the owner of the website will investigate your scraping and block you at some point.

Comment: You can check if the server answers your requests with a [429 Too many requests](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6585#section-4) response code. If yes, it tells in in the headers how long it wants you to wait until you can do the next request. If you honor these answers you should be fine.